# Access 2007 and Sharepoint - Can be viewed in webbrowser?

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access-2007

I've fairly sure this isnt possible but cannot find a yes or no answer.

We have a Access 2007 database (Faily complex, lots of VB behind the scenes) is there anyway to migrate this to sharepoint and allow people to view via a webbrowser (I assume only IE)

I cant see how this would work but again, Access 2007 and SharePoint seem to support some kind of web browser viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with SharePoint Access services. You may have to upgrade to Access 2010 first.

See: http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/archive/2009/10/19/access-services-in-sharepoint-2010-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-access-2010.aspx

Comment: and this will work with all the behind the scenes VB? But not possible in 2007 and Sharepoint 3.0?

Comment: It will not work with MOSS 2007 or WSS 3.0, you need SP 2010 Full version. For your VB scripts you need to test them to make sure, you can download an evaluation edition.